# How to test a trained Neural network in python?

Tags: neural-network

I have trained a simple NN by modifying the following code

https://www.kaggle.com/ancientaxe/simple-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python

I would now like to test it on another sample dataset. how should i proceed with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you use a model from scratch. In this case, you should run this code, as indicated in the notebook, after setting your `X` and `y` for your new test set. For more information, see the the notebook as I did not put here everything:

```py
l1 = 1/(1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(X, w1))))
l2 = 1/(1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(l1, w2))))
```

You should better use a library like Tensorflow for building NN. Tensorflow is made for that and moreover you can save your model and load it later in order to test on new testsets.